# How to display a link to my latest Tumblr post using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, tumblr

I am looking for some help and would be VERY grateful for it. I would like to use Javascript to display a link to my latest Tumblr post. For example, it would be like:

```
<a href="http://brianjsmith.tumblr.com/post/4486283258/welcome-to-my-tumblr">Read   Post</a>
```

As you can see in the above code, the link is to my latest post. However, the latest post is (of course) going to change.... I can't seem to find anything online (I've been searching Google for a few hours) and I have been trying to create my own code with Tumblr's API settings with no luck.

I know I asked a question similar to this for Twitter. Also help with getting it to execute, because apparently I can't seem to get that working either. And once again any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this will get you what you need:

```
$.getJSON('http://brianjsmith.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?',
function(response) {
   $('#myLink').attr('href',response.posts[0].url);
});
```

edit: ok, forget what i had before.  doesn't work for tumblr apparently.  this does though.

Comment: @BrianJ, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/cZmqL/5/.  just mimic what i've done there.