# How do you use js to insert json response into <a>xxxx</a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, tumblr

I am trying implement a "most recent" widget into my tumblr post. So far, I have been able to grab the top 5 most recent posts using json from this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617378/how-to-display-a-link-to-my-latest-tumblr-post-using-javascript). I want to know how to how to insert the `{title}` into the xxx so that the link shows the title of the recent posts.

I am thinking I need to use .append or .html, but I am not sure how to do it.  Can someone help me out.

javscript:

```
$.getJSON('http://brianjsmith.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?',
function(response) {
   $('#myLink').attr('href',response.posts[0].title);
});
```

html:

```
<a id=#myLink>Most recent post {title}</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myLink').attr('href',response.posts[0].url).text(response.posts[0].title);
```

***Update:***
After check the response, there is no `title` property but the `regular-title`.

```
$('#myLink').attr('href',response.posts[0].url).text(response.posts[0]['regular-title']);
```

Comment: .text part is not working for me. there is not text between <a></a> and is exactly the same without it.

Comment: @LapMingLee That is because there is no title property, did you check the response yourself, try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myLink").html('Most recent post' + response.posts[0].title)
```