# How to link to your most recent post on Tumblr?

Tags: javascript, php, html, tumblr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display a link to my latest Tumblr post using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617378/how-to-display-a-link-to-my-latest-tumblr-post-using-javascript)

Is there a way for me to link to my latest post on tumblr, bearing in mind the URL will change everytime I create a new post? I've checked the API and I'm having a hard time trying to code a link. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just read your tumblr rss feed (ie. with php) and use the link of the first item.
ie. the url for the tumblr rss feed of "nationalpost" looks like this:

```
http://nationalpost.tumblr.com/rss
```

also the xml api offerts the url for you latest post

```
http://nationalpost.tumblr.com/api/read
```

and also available as json, so you can do it with javascript

```
http://nationalpost.tumblr.com/api/read/json
```

with jQuery it could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://nationalpost.tumblr.com/api/read/json?callback=?', function(result) {
        $('#link').html('<a href="'+ result.posts[0].url +'">Latest Post</a>');
    });
});
```

and here's the [working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PdeZc/)

Comment: The link will change everytime I make a new post though. I need a URL which will always link to the lastest post. I'm positive it can be done using javascript I'm just not sure how.

Comment: also if the link changes, the proper link to your latest post will always be in this feed as the first entry!

Comment: Ah, I'm onto it thanks! Got it working on jsfiddle. How do I go about implementing it into my html template? Sorry if this is obvious haha